# Parsing HTML content to store useful information

Tags: java, html

I use the following snippet to get a web page based on the URL and some params.

```
URL url = new URL("http://location.com");
HttpURLConnection cn= (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
...
Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

I will then iterate over `in` to print the characters. That will print the raw data. I am looking for a HTML parser that create a data structure of

```
Choose the method:<br><input type="radio" name="id_radio" value="345425" onClick="setTrans()">
            <A HREF="http://server.com/view?db=mirror;trans=345425" TARGET="_new">345425</A> (<i>encoding</i>, 5239 bases)
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="http://somewhere/M_08076559" TARGET="_new">M_08076559</A>
```

Then I want to extract `value` which is `345425`, `encoding` and other things. I see some third party parsers (e.g. [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/HttpParser.htm)) but I haven't tried then due to 1) don't know if they fit my needs and 2) if there is a standard java api/package to avoid third party codes. So, is there any comment for that?

Comment: You may look this way https://jsoup.org/ a java dom parser

Comment: Looking at the documentation, that will do all the job from sending the request to receiving the response and formatting data. Am I right? With that, there is no need to use `HttpURLConnection`, `BufferedReader` and ... Do you agree?

Comment: yes that's it ;)

Comment: So, should I delete this post? I got the answer! Thanks

Comment: You can add the answer to answer to your own post, as you like